# The limit of $(\sum_{i=1}^{R} P_{i}^{q-1})^{1/(1-q)}$ as $q\to \infty$ is $1/\max P_i$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let ${}^{q}D= \bigg(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{R}\displaystyle P_{i}^{q-1} \bigg)^{1/(1-q)},$
where $q$  is the  Parameter family of diversity measure,
$R$  the number of Species,  and 
$P_{i}$ is  the Probability of the Species.

How can I  prove the following

$$ \lim _{q \rightarrow \infty} {}^{q}D=\dfrac{1}{{\max P_{i}}}$$

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to prove

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^m x_i^n \right )^{1/n} = \max x_i.$$

Assume all $x_i \geq 0$. Let $x_k = \max x_i$. The result is trivial if $x_k = 0$, so assume $x_k > 0$. Then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_k \left ( \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i/x_k)^n \right )^{1/n}$$

by factoring $x_k^n$ from each term in the sum. Having done this, the sum is now bounded above regardless of $n$, because each term is at most $1$ and there are $m$ terms. The sum is also bounded below, because the $x_i$ are nonnegative and the $k$th term is always $1$. So there is some $L \in [1,m]$ that the sum converges to. Then your limit is $x_k L^0 = x_k$, as desired.

This incidentally is the standard result that $\lim_{p \to \infty} \| x \|_p = \| x \|_\infty$, which is the motivation for the notation $\| \cdot \|_\infty$.